# Cross joining sql tables by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cross-join

I have a following table , table1

```
date            value   
-------------------------
2015-01-01      0
2015-01-02      0
2015-01-03      0
2015-01-04      0
```

And have a table2

```
datestart       dateend         value   
-------------------------------------
2015-01-02      2015-01-03      1
```

I would like to get a results like following

```
date            value   
-------------------------
2015-01-01      0
2015-01-02      1
2015-01-03      1
2015-01-04      0
```

I tried to use cross apply

```
select table1.date, temp.value
from table1
cross join
(select table2.value from table2 where
table2.startdate <= table1.date and table2.enddate > table1.date) as temp
```

but I end up with

```
date            value   
-------------------------
2015-01-02      1
2015-01-03      1
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join like this:

```
select table1.date, coalesce(table2.value,0) Value
from table1
left join table2
on table1.date between table2.startdate and table2.enddate 
order by 1
```

Although it'll get messy if you have overlapping dates in table 2.  This may not be what you intended, but if you wanted to sum all values of the ranges that each date falls into you would do something like this:

```
select table1.date, sum(coalesce(table2.value,0)) Value
from table1
left join table2
on table1.date between table2.startdate and table2.enddate 
group by table1.date
```

Otherwise you would get duplicate dates in your output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cross join, but a left join:

```
SELECT    table1.date, table2.value
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.date BETWEEN table2.startdate AND table2.enddate
```

Comment: after running your code, i get the same result as mine. i want to have all dates from table1 (tally table containing all 365/366 days) but with the changed value depending on value in table2.

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT JOIN` will do here:

```
SELECT table1.date, table2.value
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN
table2
ON table2.startdate <= table1.date
AND table2.enddate > table1.date
```

Comment: this code does not return dates not mentioned in table2 with value 0

Comment: @mko: you're right. Instead of `table2.value`, use `COALESCE(table2.value, table1.value)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query.  I have changed the column name date to mydate.I guess date is a keyword.

```
  select t1.mydate, (case when t2.value is null then 0 else t2.value end) as value from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 
    on t1.mydate between t2.datestart and t2.dateend order by mydate;
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85265/1

Comment: I used coalesce(table2.value,0)